# Where is the migrations source files?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

When I do:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

I get this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'CreatePasswordRemindersTable' not found
```

I have no migration for CreatePasswordRemindersTable in my project, I don't from where Laravel is trying to migrate this?

I tried to do composer dump-autoload, composer update but I am stuck at the same error

I tried to seach for `CreatePasswordRemindersTable` in my project folder file's content, but there isn't any result for it.

Any idea?

Comment: The files are usually timestamped, and named in lowercase. Something like this: `2015_10_12_000000_create_password_reminders_table`. Check the `/database/migrations` folder for a file like this.

Comment: you may have used the model or route model binding etc, check where you have used this migration's model,find its use and comment it, then try

Answer (score 0):

Check the migrations table in your database. You probably created a migration at some point and then you deleted the corresponding file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a `composer dump-autoload` fixes the "Class not found" problems.